# How to design the database to use for ordering by

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've table `post`, `answer` and `like` were tables `answer` and `like` are related to table `post` like this.

**table post**

```
post_id      post_content   ....
```

**table answer**

```
answer_id      post_id     answer_content     ...
```

**table like**

```
like_id      post_id      ...
```

So, In my news feed page I want to show all post which can order by `most` or `least` `answers` or `likes` of these posts.

Here what I can figured out and I'm using right now.

```
SELECT p.*,
           COUNT(DISTINCT a.id) AS `answer_count`,
           COUNT(DISTINCT l.id) AS `like_count`
      FROM post p
  LEFT JOIN answer a
        ON a.post_id = p.post_id 
  LEFT JOIN like l
        ON l.post_id = p.post_id
  GROUP BY p.id
  ORDER BY ...
```

In `ORDER BY` it can be `p.created`, `answer_count` or `like_count`

But here is my question..
What is commonly way of database designing to sort data with other tables.

 1. Use counting from other tables like i said.
 2. Created new columns in `post` table to store `answers` and `likes`.

Thanks for help and advice.

Comment: you can order by any of those? it just depends on what you want for the data.. not sure why you would change your database design for just ordering

Comment: i think it slow if using count from other multiple of tables, it easy way to do but it use much of executed time.

Comment: no.. thats not true... because if you use the order by on a count.. you can reference the alias.. meaning you can reference the name you gave a count... instead of doing the count again.

Comment: try doing `ORDER BY answer_count` that will execute and work properly instead of doing the COUNT(DISTINCT a.id) again.

Comment: Yeah, I've done as you said but still found that seems slow.

Comment: have you tried it without the order by? what indexes do you have on the tables? that is going to be your issue... not changing the database design.

Comment: I don't have an indexes in any tables and just have only a primary key as follow. table post is `post_id`, table answer is `answer_id` and table like is `like_id`. please explain how indexes work different from primary key.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

Comment: I think indexes may not solved my problems as well, because to find all answers of each posts, it has to compare every `post_id` with answer table to return each answers count of entire posts

Comment: The problem is not with the COUNT(). The problem is within these lines: `LEFT JOIN answer a ON a.post_id = p.post_id LEFT JOIN like l ON l.post_id = p.post_id`. You've mentioned that you have not any indexes in your `answer` and `like` tables. Looks like you need one in each for the post_id column

Comment: Ok, how should i do to solve this

Comment: You should familiarize yourself with indexing. It is a different concept than de-duplication but is an equally important part of SQL optimization. Consider adding indexes where you know column combinations will be unique. If the number of rows is great and any of the columns in your data contain any kind of algorithm or sortable substring, etc. then consider a HASH index to greatly improve your query's performance. To get you started here is some recommended reading.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/column-indexes.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/multiple-column-indexes.html